# Sprint annotation based 404 handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I want to handle any 404 Exceptions and redirect these requests to my dashboard.
On an web.xml based config it was easy with

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/weberror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I currently have an annotation based config so I don't want to handle it like that, I tried the following but that didn't work with `ResourceNotFoundException`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@Autowired private LoginUserService loginUserService;

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleGeneralException(Exception exception) {
    ...
}

@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public ModelAndView handleAccessException(AccessDeniedException exception) {
    return new ModelAndView("accessDeniedView");
}

//this isn't working!!! I'd like to handle it my 404 but still my apache 404 page comes up instead
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException exception) {
    return new ModelAndView("dashboardView");
}
}
```

Comment: try with `<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/weberror.jsp</location>
 </error-page>`

Comment: what is your "testcase"? you enter non-existing URL or do you throw `ResourceNotFoundException` from your controller?

Comment: Can you please tell us ResourceNotFoundException belong to which API liberary? I'm not able to find in the Spring jars and it seems belongs to velocity jar.  Can you try handling this exception with NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException class which is there in the spring framework?

Comment: @user3247727 Sadly that doesn't work...
And yes it was from the velocity char

Comment: you may like looking at  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page as @ExceptionHandler is limited to handle mapping exceptions arising from controllers

Answer (score 0):

you can replace error page for error status like this :

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  //
      @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
        public void handleConflict() {
                           // Nothing to do
       }
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, simply returns the apache 404 page again

Answer (score 0):

Please have a  look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page, you will need an controller like below to handle all such errors.

@Controller
public class ErrorController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/error", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> handle(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("status", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"));
    map.put("reason", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));

    return map;
}
```

}